# working out logs? (algorithms)

Tags: logarithm

can someone please explain to me, how to work out logs?

e.g. `log27` to the power 3 ?

I though the above is 3 because `3x3x3=27` and it takes 3, 3's to make 27. is this correct?

Comment: This is not on-topic here. See http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of logarithm states that if log<sub>b</sub>(x) = y then b<sup>y</sup> = x. This works for real numbers, not just integers.

In your example, log<sub>3</sub>(27) = 3, because 3<sup>3</sup> = 27.

Or your second example: log<sub>3</sub>(11) = 2.182658..., because 3<sup>2.182658...</sup> = 11.

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Definition).

Answer (score 1):

log27 to the base 3 is 3.

Because 27 can be written as 3*3*3. 
In the same way if someone asks for log64 to the base 4 then the value will be 3.

4*4*4 = 64.